# void return types using reference variables in c++

Tags: c++, variables, reference

I have been working on this C++ source file for weeks and do not understand where I am going wrong at..

```
//This program will ask the user for the measurement of all 3 sides of a triangle
//and first determine if the numbers will equal a triangle, then give the area and
//perimeter of the triangle.

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void calc(double , double , double ,double &, double &);
void s(double , double , double , double &);

int main()
{       
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
    double per;
    double sr;
    double areat;

    cout<<"Enter the three side of your triangle: ";
    cin>> a >> b >> c;
    per = a+b+c;

    if (a > b || a < b || b > c || b < c)
    {
        cout<< "Sorry, this is not a triangle.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"For a Triangle with the sides of "<<a<<", "<<b<<",and " <<c <<endl; 
        cout<< setprecision(3)<<fixed<<showpoint;
        cout<<"The Perimeter is "<<per<<endl;
        calc(a,b,c,sr,areat);
        cout<< "The Area is "<<areat<<endl;
    } 
    system ("pause");
    return 0; 
}    

void s(double a, double b, double c, double &sr)
{
    sr = (a+b+c)/2;
}

void calc(double a, double b, double c, double &sr, double &areat)
{
    areat = sqrt(sr*(sr-a)*(sr-b)*(sr-c));
}
```

Comment: please reformat the code, and let us know where is the issue

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Don't just say "it doesn't work", give us some details so we can help you.

Comment: It compiles and runs for me.  What's the problem, exactly?

Answer (score 5):

You aren't calling function `s()`, therefore variable `sr` is not getting initialized.

Other minor things:

```
if (a > b || a < b || b > c || b < c)
    cout << "Sorry, this is not a triangle.\n";
```

This line will reject all triangles unless a == b == c. Did you intend to limit to equilateral triangles?

In function `calc()`, `sr` is not an output, it does not need to be passed by reference.

Comment: Aaaahhh you got there faster than I could type. +1.

Comment: The same goes for `calc`, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @NineFingers Apparently you need more fingers </obviousjoke>

Comment: @Zecc Haha, +1 to that. Logen Ninefingers from Joe Abercombie's The First Law. Read it, it's awesome. Unfortunately I was going for a long-winded post; David got there much more concisely. Concise is better.

Comment: @Zecc: I was about to write that :-D

Comment: Yes, I intend to limit to equilateral triangles. How can I call these functions?  I am really new to C++ and I have understood everything up to this.  Also, I have noticed that people say that the source code is hard to read, how can I make this more easy to read?

Comment: To the other people, It does not work because it is not calling the functions.  Other than that, it is working fine.